# How to make binance-options request?

Tags: python

I can't understand how to make requests to Binance API.

I have tried:

```
url='https://eapi.binance.com/eapi/v1/trades'
request_param={'symbol':'BTC-13JAN23-15000-C'}
data=requests.get('url,params=request_param')
print(data.json())
```

And I'm always getting this Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\МОЕ\Python_script\Request_Binance.py", line 4, in <module>
    data=requests.get('url,params=request_param')
  File "C:\Users\m.frolov.PBG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\m.frolov.PBG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\m.frolov.PBG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 573, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Users\m.frolov.PBG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 484, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "C:\Users\m.frolov.PBG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 368, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "C:\Users\m.frolov.PBG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 439, in prepare_url
    raise MissingSchema(
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'url,params=request_param': No scheme supplied. Perhaps you meant http://url,params=request_param?
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to wrap the variable in quotation marks. Also you should use another format for the symbol name.

For example, to get trades for a call option that expires at 30 June 2023 with a strike equal 15000:

```py
url = 'https://eapi.binance.com/eapi/v1/trades'
request_param = {'symbol': 'BTC-230630-15000-C'}
data = requests.get(url, params=request_param)
print(data.json())
```